# How to add an indicator under the active bottom tab?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I need to add an indicator for the active tab I tried to add a borderBottom with `tabStyle` but we can't check focused with that.

Using `react-navigation v5` and `createBottomTabNavigator` for bottom tabs.

[image: Here's the output image]

Here's my code:

```
<BottomTab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: colors.brown,
        labelPosition: 'below-icon',
      }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeTabNav}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            return focused ? (
              <HomeSelectedIcon height={ms(24)} width={ms(24)} />
            ) : (
              <HomeIcon height={ms(24)} width={ms(24)} />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
     ...
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out myself by making a custom tabbar icon if someone needs to achieve this using the bottom-tab bar only.

Here's the code.

```
<BottomTab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: colors.brown,
        showLabel: false,
        tabStyle: styles.tabStyle,
        style: styles.tabContainerStyle,
      }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeTabNav}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            return focused ? (
              <View style={styles.labelFocusedContainer}>
                <HomeSelectedIcon height={24} width={24} />
                <Text style={styles.labelFocusedStyle}>Home</Text>
              </View>
            ) : (
              <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
                <HomeIcon height={24} width={24} />
                <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>Home</Text>
              </View>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
   ...
</BottomTab.Navigator>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  labelContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
  },
  labelFocusedContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    borderBottomWidth: 3,
    borderBottomColor: colors.brown,
  },
  labelFocusedStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginVertical: 8,
    color: colors.brown,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    fontSize: 10,
  },
  labelStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginVertical: 8,
    color: colors.veryDarkgray,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    fontSize: 10,
  },
});
```

But the best and easy way to do this is by using `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` and using these props.

```
tabBarPosition="bottom"
      tabBarOptions={{
        showIcon: true,
        pressOpacity: 1,
        iconStyle: styles.iconStyle,
        showLabel: true,
        activeTintColor: colors.brown,
        indicatorStyle: {
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: colors.brown,
        },
```

Comment: Once check my answer your answer seems outdated. I have a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

This does not seem to be possible / easily achievable with bottom-tabs, but you could use the material version - `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs` and configure it to match your needs, specifically using `tabBarPosition="bottom"` and `tabBarOptions={{ indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor } }}`.

You can check more options in the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#tabbaroptions

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tabs.Navigator tabBarPosition="bottom" tabBarOptions={{ indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red' } }}>
        <Tabs.Screen name="screen 1" component={View} />
        <Tabs.Screen name="screen 2" component={View} />
      </Tabs.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best answer would be to use the `tabBarButton` prop to override and add your own custom styles to the container of the tab button.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabbarbutton

```
const CustomTabButton = (props) => (
    <Pressable
        {...props}
        style={
            props.accessibilityState.selected
                ? [props.style, styles.activeTab]
                : props.style
        }
    />
)
```

`styles.activeTab` is the custom style you want to add, be careful to spread the `props.style` to get the default styles from the library like width, padding, height etc

`props.accessibilityState.selected` will add styles according to condition if you want styles for all the tabs you can remove the condition.

Inside `screeenOptions` prop on navigator or the `option` props of each screen.

```
tabBarButton: CustomTabButton
```

Using material top tab is not a good solution because it does not support well with a keyboard. But bottom tabs do work well with the keyboard.